# I'm learning JavaFX but I can't make a ListView load its items

Tags: listview, model-view-controller, javafx

I'm trying to build an application with `JavaFX` and I'm having some trouble when I load a view's controller, besides I'm trying to follow the `mvc` pattern so here it's my problem

```
package mark.findme.address.view;


import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import mark.findme.address.MainApp;

public class AppMenuViewController
{
    @FXML
    private ListView<String> lista;

   private final static ObservableList<String> items=FXCollections.observableArrayList ("Clientes","Gestión sección", "Estadísticas","Faturación","Inventario","Productos","Proveedores");

// Reference to the main application.
private MainApp mainApp;

@FXML
private void initialize()
{
    lista = new ListView<String>();
    lista.setItems(items);
    System.out.println("Cargué las listas");
}
public void setMainApp(MainApp nMainApp)
{
    mainApp = nMainApp;


}
}
```

I can't make this to work I need when I load the view It load its items.

Here it's where I'm loading this controller

```
package mark.findme.address;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import mark.findme.address.view.AppMenuViewController;

public class MainApp extends Application
{
private Stage escenarioPrincipal;
private BorderPane rootLayout;
/*
 * Inicio de la aplicacion
 */
@Override
public void start(Stage nEscenarioPrincipal)
{
    escenarioPrincipal = nEscenarioPrincipal;
    escenarioPrincipal.setTitle("Find Me");



    initRootLayout();
    loadAppMenu();
}
public void initRootLayout()
{
    try {
        // Carga el archivo del diseño de la raiz.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

        // Muestra la escena en el diseño de la raiz.
        // La escenario se le asigna la escena que debe mostrar.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        escenarioPrincipal.setScene(scene);
        escenarioPrincipal.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
public void loadAppMenu()
{
    try
    {
        // Carga AppMenuView
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/AppMenuView.fxml"));
        AnchorPane appMenuView = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        // Asigna al centro de la aplicacion appMenuView
        rootLayout.setCenter(appMenuView);

        // Dar al controlador acceso al main de la aplicacion
        AppMenuViewController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainApp(this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public Stage getEscenarioPrincipal()
{
    return escenarioPrincipal;
}

public void setEscenarioPrincipal(Stage nEscenarioPrincipal)
{
    escenarioPrincipal = nEscenarioPrincipal;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}

}
```

I already using `sceneBuilder` told my `view` which was its `controller` and when I run it appers an empty `listview`

Comment: I did this, but still it doesn't load it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

You have one problem in your code: You create a **new** ListView in your Controller

#### Solution

If you create a FXML, attach a controller and annotate some variables with @FXML, there is everything done, if the FXML will load without errors. All instances are there.

So, normally you should simply **remove** this line from your controller:

```
lista = new ListView<String>();
```